# Do Rocks DB or Level DB write log even when compaction?

Tags: database, key-value-store, leveldb, rocksdb

I just know when Rocks DB gets write operation, it writes log first for consistency. And I know if Memtable is flushed, it deletes that log. 
I'm curious that when a new SSTable by compaction is flushed, does Rocks DB write log for that a new SSTable too? If not, how do Rocks DB guarantee consistency for a new SSTable by compaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it writes metadata into manifest file otherwise the log file. You can find the related statements in function logandapply().

Comment: Thank you, It was very helpful. As a result of seeing the code, the compacted key-value records aren't logged. Only descriptors such as the previous version information are logged on Level DB.

Comment: @HoyoungLee Yes, manifest file only holds metadata, and kv records are saved in log before written into sstables. You can read function recover() in db_impl.cc for that routine.

Comment: I cannot found mechanism that writes to log for output file (the new sstable created by compaction) on DBImpl::DoCompactionWork(), which actually do compaction.  I think that Level DB just do roll back recovery for compaction by referring to manifest. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, data log is just for memtable. Leveldb only logs metadata of new sstables by using manifest file. Data log and manifest file works together to maintain consistency.